# Solution wants to change project GUID when adding

Tags: visual-studio, guid, projects-and-solutions

in our team we have multiple solutions with shared projects. At some point somehow the project guids changed when referencing the shared project. So I decided to tidy up all solutions so that all of them are using the same guid for the project.

Now when I try to add the project again, the solution wants to change the project guid when adding it to the solution and I don't get why. The new guid is a random guid everytime I add it.

This is what I did:

- removed that shared project from the solution
- removed all project references to that project from other projects within the solution
- performed a clean on the solution
- manually deleted the output
- finally added the project to the solution again

**edit:** I have gone though [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377286/project-guid-keeps-changing) post already and fixed the guid manually. But after opening the solution again, the guid is changed to a random one :-(

Does anybody have an idea why the solution still wants to change the project guid? What am I missing?

Comment: This [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377286/project-guid-keeps-changing) may be useful?  It suggests that TFS effects it, and one answer links to a workaround.

Comment: The 2nd answer by Ty H. looks more promising, as it references Visual Studio 2013 and gives instructions for an actual solution.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone through that post already, but even when I add the project, fix the guid manually and then I open the solution again, it changed it back to a random guid

Answer (score 3):

This happens if you have two projects with the same guid in the same solution, VS will assign a new guid to one of them.

Comment: Like I said in the question, this happens even if I manually fix the project GUID

Comment: pass then, your question is similar to something I've seen but maybe it's not quite the same

Answer (score 1):

Like Tim said:
"This happens if you have two projects with the same guid in the same solution, VS will assign a new guid to one of them."

This can be happen when a new solution with a new Project is build and if you insert shared projects they may have a guid that is the same like the new project.
The problem is that all other solutions which have also the shared prject already inserted have to change the guid again and thats annoyingly.

A simple Solution instead of editing the solution- and project-files by hand:
Just remove the projects and then insert the shared projects FIRST and AFTER THAT insert the NEW project. So VS gives a new - not duplicate - guid to the new project and is not forced to change the guid of the shared projects.

... so much for the topic "Globally Unique Identifier" ;-)