# Visual Studio replace GUIDs in sln file

Tags: c#, .net, git, bitbucket

We use bitbucket on the project and write it in C#, my partner uses Rider, and I use Visual Studio. In the process we found out that the GUIDs in the `.sln` file is changing - what could be the problem and how to deal with it?

[GUIDs diff after fetching or rebasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciF5s.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Project GUID keeps changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377286/project-guid-keeps-changing)

Comment: Thanks to @marc-s for editing my question! I'm from Russia and I don't write well in English.